# plt.scatter: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Tags: python, numpy

I want to plot a simple scatter diagram on my dataset.

```
# Create polynomial features
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
X_train_poly = poly.fit_transform(X_train_imputed)
X_test_poly = poly.transform(X_test_imputed)
# Train a Linear Regression model on the polynomial features
poly_reg = LinearRegression()
poly_reg.fit(X_train_poly, y_train)
# Make predictions
y_pred_poly = poly_reg.predict(X_test_poly)

#sketch the polynomial regression on the dataset
# Plot the polynomial regression
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.scatter(X_test_imputed['Level_of_Hemoglobin'], y_test, color='blue', label='Actual')  # line 173
plt.plot(X_test_imputed['Level_of_Hemoglobin'], y_pred_poly, color='red', linewidth=2, label='Predicted')
plt.xlabel('Level_of_Hemoglobin')
plt.ylabel('Blood Pressure')
plt.title('Polynomial Regression')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

but getting the following error on line 173

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

how should I fix this error? and what is exactly causing this error?

Comment: It seems that `X_test_imputed` is a NumPy array. You can't use a string to index it.

Comment: How you can solve it depends on what you intended `X_test_imputed` to be. If you did not intend it to be a NumPy array, you need to change the code that creates it. If it is a NumPy array intentionally, you need to change `X_test_imputed['Level_of_Hemoglobin']` to something else (perhaps to `X_test_imputed`).

Comment: yeah, it's just imputed and of missing values removed version of X-test in the model. and I didn't use numpy for that

Comment: But some library you are using did.